# CSS: Animate right column over left column on hover

Tags: css

I have this two-column setup here where the right column animates over the left column on hover. The left column should not shrink:

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/xv8KV/1/

**Is there a way of achieving the same result without using position absolute?** The position absolute is [causing headache elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900388/headroom-js-stops-working-due-to-position-absolute-content).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column_1"></div>
    <div class="column_2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.column_1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 120px);
    height: 600px;
    background: blue;
}
.column_2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    -webkit-transition: 500ms width;
    -moz-transition: 500ms width;
    -ms-transition: 500ms width;
    -o-transition: 500ms width;
    transition: 500ms width;
}
.column_2:hover {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You mention the right column three times in your opening sentence. Do you mean left column for the latter two usages?

Comment: Also in my browser (Chrome 34.0.1847.137 on Linux) the left column does not shrink as the right column expands.

Comment: @DrewNoakes apparently my post was edited by someone else to mention the right column three times. Let me fix that.

Comment: Actually the edit was just tags, but it doesn't matter :)

Comment: Oh ok, my bad. Anyway please see the edit :)

Comment: Yes, the left column not shrinking is correct behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `float` property.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.column_2 {
  margin-right: 120px;
  height: 600px;
  background: blue;
}

.column_1 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  float: right;
  -webkit-transition: 500ms width;
  -moz-transition: 500ms width;
  -ms-transition: 500ms width;
  -o-transition: 500ms width;
  transition: 500ms width;
}

.column_1:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hover the green column</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="column_1"></div>
  <div class="column_2"></div>
</div>
```

PS: I interchanged the stylings to the columns.

Comment: @MarkBoulder [just a note] even the parent container doesn't require `position: relative`.

Comment: Indeed! By the way is this possible without interchanging the two? Having the 2nd column coming first in my markup doesn't quite feel natural.

Comment: Actually there's a problem -- despite the blue column not shrinking, its content does shrink: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/xv8KV/3/ -- is there a way around this?

Comment: @MarkBoulder then I think position absolute is definitely required here. [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xv8KV/5/).